# Replacing enumerate to output a string

Tags: python

I have written a code that reads a text file containing several paragraphs.I have used enumerate but want to replace enumerate() with a simple loop

```
file=open("file1.txt","r")
text="target"
for i, line in enumerate(file, 1):
    if text in line:
        print (i, line)
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by replacing `enumerate` with a "simple loop"?

Comment: What's the point in *not* using built-in functions? Most of the times built-ins make code shorter, more readable *and* faster.

Comment: Don't use `file` as a variable name, it's a built-in function.

Comment: When a teacher tells you not to use **basic** built-in functions, you should say _"why not?"_

Comment: Uh oh.... `print` is inbuilt, and so is `open`... better do some more removing :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea why you would want to do this, however this is an equivalent:

```
file=open("file1.txt","r")
text="target"
count=0
for line in file:
    count += 1
    if text in line:
        print (count, line)
```

Answer (score 1):

`enumerate` can can be replaced easily with a simple generator function:

```
def enumerate(iterable, start=0):
    for item in iterable:
        yield start, item
        start += 1
```

Comment: thank you but i should not use yield() as well. I should only use some basic functions line read(), readline().

Comment: @Pramod `yield` is not a function, it's a statement. Like `return`, but a bit different.